# Node.js error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc"

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I am using node.js on digital ocean and trying to run a file upload / download server.

To make sure the server runs in the background and does not quit on error, I am using the following

`nohup nodejs server.js &`

I am using `nodejs` instead of the `node` command because that is what digital ocean recommends.
This server is almost exlusively for uploading and downloading files.  This works, for about two files, but then the server crashes with the following error:

`"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'   what():  std::bad_alloc"`

I have no idea what is causing this, and I would appreciate any help. Preventing the crash would be great but also making it so the node server would not crash would also be great.  I thought that is what `nohup` does, but apparently not.  (I also haven't been able to get forever working correctly).

Here is the code for my server:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    util = require('util'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    qs = require('querystring');


var formidable = require('formidable'),
    mime = require('mime');
var account = {username: 'test', password: 'etc'};
var accounts = [account],
    port = 9090,




function dirTree(filename) {
    var stats = fs.lstatSync(filename),
        info = {
            name: path.basename(filename),
            path: ip + ':' + port + '/uploads/finished/' + path.basename(filename),
            type: mime.lookup(filename).substring(0, 5)
        };

    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        info.type = "folder";
        info.children = fs.readdirSync(filename).map(function(child) {
            return dirTree(filename + '/' + child);
        });
    }
    return info;
}



http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    if(request.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        var filePath = './content' + request.url;
        if (filePath == './content/') {
            filePath = './content/home.html';
        }
        if (filePath == './content/feed') {
            a = dirTree('./content/uploads/finished');
            response.end(JSON.stringify(a));
        }
        var extname = path.extname(filePath);
        var contentType = mime.lookup(extname);
        fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {
            if (exists) {
                fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, content) {
                    if (error) {
                        response.writeHead(500);
                        response.end();
                    }
                    else {
                        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
                        response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                    }
                })
            } else {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.end();
            }
        });
    }


    if (request.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm;
        if (request.url == '/verify') {
            form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {
                for (i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
                    if (fields.username == accounts[i].username && fields.password == accounts[i].password) {
                        fs.readFile('./content/uploadForm.html', function (error, content) {
                            if (error) {
                                response.end('There was an error');
                            } else {
                                response.end(content);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        fs.readFile('./content/invalidLogin.html', function (error, content) {
                            if (error) {
                                response.end('There was an error');
                            } else {
                                response.end(content);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if (request.url == '/upload') {
                var oldPath,
                newPath,
                fileName;

            form.uploadDir = './content/uploads/temp/';
            form.keepExtensions = true;
            form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {
                type = files['upload']['type'];
                fileName = files['upload']['name'];
                oldPath = files['upload']['path'];
                newPath = './content/uploads/finished/' + fileName;
            });

            form.on('end', function () {
                fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        response.end('There was an error with your request');
                        console.log('error')
                    } else {
                        response.end('<h1>Thanks for uploading ' + fileName + '<h1>');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}).listen(port);
console.log('listening on ' + port);
```

Comment: What does `nodejs -v` say?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your script is just run out of the available memory.

Most likely you upload or download very large file and you read complete file in memory while receiving or sending.

You should rewrite you code using stream operations and process files chunk-by-chunk instead.